# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser - Remove Script Data

Tags: php

I'm using the last version from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/).

There's a `remove_noise()` function that is called on `load()` that looks to remove any script data, which would be great. However, it doesn't seem to work.

When parsing TechCrunch dot com and looking for all H2's (as an example), there's a lot of CDATA within a script tag. This is crashing my PHP script and would think the remove_noise() function actually cleans the output.

Am I missing something on functionality to get `clean/removed` output?

Comment: add your code in the question not in a separate link
check how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After requesting support directly from the project on [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/support-requests/47/), it turns out everything is working as expected and that regex had a limit which needed to be increased.

The code which helped me troubleshoot the issue is below:

```
<?php
// Normal regex doesn't work for such a large script section. The regex parser hits the backtrack limit, so we need to increase it temporarily.
ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', '10485760'); // 10MB

// The total file size of the webpage is also much bigger than normally allowed. Use this definition to increase the upper boundary of the parser.
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 10485760); // 10MB

include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('https://techcrunch.com/');

// This will list all headers
foreach($html->find('h2') as $h2) echo $h2->plaintext . PHP_EOL;

// Use this code to remove script tags from the DOM (i.e. if you need to save the DOM for later use. In my tests the file size went down from 1.9MB to 30KB
foreach($html->find('script') as $script) $script->remove();
```